# Old Win7 system created Homegroup but no longer on network

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, home-networking

I had an old Win7 system and I created a Homegroup that all my computers joined. The system has been taken out of service so I can no longer access the homegroup password to add new computers.

I just added a Win10 system and it can't create a new homegroup and I can't join the one on the old Win7 system because I don't have the password.

How do I get rid of the homegroup for all my current networked computers and make it where I can network my computers again?

Comment: I was actually able to get the password by viewing it on another computer but I'd really like to have all computers leave that homegroup and start a new one since the computer that created it is no longer on the network

Comment: You can do that by leaving the homegroup on each computer. Since homegroups are sort of peer-to-peer, I don't think you'll really see any benefit to recreating it. I've had issues sometimes where a computers homegroup configuration will sort of get "stuck" but powering off that computer and setting up the homegroup from other ones then turning it back on usually fixes it

Comment: Problem is, when I go to join a new homegroup, the only one that shows is the one from the old computer.

Comment: But weren't you able to get the password from another computer in the homegroup?

Comment: @MB34 You need to create a new HomeGroup on one computer, and have all the others join it. In order to do so, type 'Homegroup' in Search and click on HomeGroup. Select 'Create a new HomeGroup' and click 'Next'. Now join it on all your other computers. If you're unable to do so, disband the other homegroup by having all computers leave it, and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for starters :

1. Ensure that all your computers :

   - Have Internet Protocol Version 6 enabled
   - Are all on WORKGROUP
   - Are all logging-on with Microsoft accounts, or alternatively are all logging-on with local accounts
2. Shut down all other computers on the network leaving only the Windows 10 computer
3. Reboot the Windows 10 computer
4. You should now be able to create a new Homegroup on the Windows 10 computer
5. Turn on the other computers one by one and join them to it.